# Is it dangerous to run a web application server on Java 5.0?

Tags: java, security

Java 5 is End-Of-Life since [April 2008](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/eol-135779.html). We're mid-2014 and my customer is still using it to run their application servers, with a public web access from the Internet. I want to warn them about the risks and provide them with good reasons to migrate to most recent versions of Java, maybe even Java 8.

I remember reading news about huge security flaws with Java 5 for which bugfixes aren't released anymore, but I can't find a precise example.

Is there a severe unpatched vulnerability of Java 5 which would mandate a customer to update to a recent version of Java?

Comment: Nearly all Java security issues are related to the browser plugin and thus to applets. I don't recall any serious issues when running an application server

Comment: I don't think there were any serious security issues in Java 5. This issue would be that you have to run an ancient WebServer that still supports Java 5, this **will** have security holes.

Comment: The cacerts file in java 5 is ancient and will still trust compromised certificates like the diginotar one.

Comment: Also, I'd expect trouble in the SSL implementation.

Comment: Examples tend to be vague but how about https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2013-5830

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I always was thinking the same, but it is not all clear. And being honest, when security policies are wrong applied to plugin code why they should be all correct in other parts of JRE ? http://www.pcworld.com/article/2036202/serious-flaw-present-in-latest-java-runtime-environment-for-desktops-and-servers-researchers-say.html

Comment: The security issues for the plugin were all about possibilities to escape the plugin sandbox and compromise the client computer where the browser is running. The JRE that runs the application server is something entirely different. Security issues in your application server or your (web) application itself are far more critical there.

Comment: "Security issues in your application server or your (web) application itself are far more critical there." => Yes, but plugins run code from a website whereas you're the author of the code which runs on an application server, is it correct?

Comment: Free downloads for Java 5 were indeed stopped several years ago, but commercial support is still available from Oracle: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/eol-135779.html

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name The risk is different. The whole world has had plenty time to find vulnerabilities in Java 5. You may expect that off the shelf exploits of these vulnerabilities are available to people wishing to do harm. The custom code running on the server is more likely way less secure but also less well known and less well studied. People will need to do some original thinking of their own if they wish to exploit its vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most famous security holes in Java are those in the Java Plugin in the browser. But on the application server, Java handles the low level networking and things like time zones and XML handling. It is allowed broad access to the server resources and therefore indeed a security risk.

SSL relies on an up to date cacerts keystore and the one supplied with Java 5 update 22 is ancient and will trust old and unreliable certificate signing authorities and won't recognize new ones.

Oracle still offers support for Java 5. It's called Java 5 Advanced, formerly known as Java For Business. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/overview-137139.html contains an overview of all the patches they've released since Java 5 went End Of Life. They're currently at Java 5 update 85.

The overview links to descriptions of Critical Patch Updates like http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/security/cpuoct2013-1899837.html#AppendixJAVA . When it comes to security issues, these updates give only vague, but nonetheless rather worrying descriptions, such as the description of CVE-2013-5830:

```
Protocol: Multiple
Subcomponent: Libraries
Remote Exploit without Auth.?: Yes
Base Score: 10 (out of 10)
Access Vector: Network
Access Complexity: Low
Authentication: None
Confidentiality: Complete
Integrity: Complete
Availability: Complete
Versions affected: Java SE 5.0u51 and earlier
```

This issue affects servers as well as clients. Note 1 says:

> Applies to client **and server deployment** of Java. This vulnerability can be exploited through sandboxed Java Web Start applications and sandboxed Java applets. **It can also be exploited by supplying data to APIs in the specified Component without using sandboxed Java Web Start applications or sandboxed Java applets, such as through a web service.**

I am no security expert but pessimistically read this as: Please be aware that anybody can easily send offensive input to the server and wreak all possible sorts of havoc it.

This is just one of multiple server side CVE's patched since update 22.

The actual updates are only available to Java 5 Advanced customers. You could suggest that your customer avail themselves of this support. Or that they compare the price of getting support to the cost of upgrading.